# Javascript loop strangeness - wont stop, only

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am fairly new to jQuery and JavaScript, so forgive me if I am overlooking something very obvious.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to load a json file, then for each item in the json array, display its contents for a few seconds, then move onto the next item in the array.

However, what is happening is that the loop never ends and it seems to continuously loop over the last item in the array.

Here is my code. including some of the various I have tried in the comments:

```
    var maps;
    var isInitialView;
    $(document).ready(function () {



    //$.getJSON("/Services/Maps.svc/GetMaps", callback);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/Maps.svc/GetMaps",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: callback
    });


    function callback(data) {
        console.log("inside callback");
        maps = data;
        isInitialView = true;
        rotateMapDetails();
    };


    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: false });

    //    $.getJSON("/Services/Maps.svc/GetMaps",
    //      function (data) {
    //          isInitialView = true;
    //          maps = data;
    //          //          for (var map in maps.d) {
    //          //              alert(map.MapName);
    //          //              $('#accordion').delay(delay).fadeIn(400, populateMapDetails(map)).fadeOut(400);
    //          //          }
    //          //          //rotateMapDetails();
    //          //          $.each(maps.d, function (key, map) {
    //          //              var delay = 1000;
    //          //              //alert("inside getJson loop, and mapName is :" + map.MapName);
    //          //              //$('#accordion').delay(delay).fadeIn(400, populateMapDetails(map)).fadeOut(400);
    //          //              //              sleep(delay);
    //          //              setInterval(function () {
    //          //                  populateMapDetails(map);
    //          //              }, 5000);
    //          //              //populateMapDetails(map);
    //          //$('#accordion').fadeOut(400);
    //          //              sleep(delay);
    //          // });
    //          //rotateMapDetails();
    //          console.log("inside getJson");
    //      }); 

    $('#accordion').load(function () {
        alert("accordion loaded");
        rotateMapDetails();
    });

    function rotateMapDetails() {
        var size = $(maps.d).length;
        console.log("maps.d has " + size + " elements");


        var delay = 4000;

                for (var map in maps.d) {
                    console.log("inside for loop");
                    console.log(maps.d[map]);
                    setInterval(function () {
                        populateMapDetails(maps.d[map]);
                                      }, delay);
                }



     //                for (var i=0;i<=size;i++)
      //                    {
      //                        setInterval(function () {
      //                            console.log(maps.d);
      //                            console.log(maps.d[i]);
      //                                     populateMapDetails(maps.d[i]);
      //                                 }, delay);
      //                    };



        //        $(maps.d).each(function (map) {
        //            if (isInitialView) {
        //                //var map = $(this);
        //                var delay = 4000;
        //                setInterval(function () {
        //                    console.log("inside rotateMapDetails and map is " + map.MapName);
        //                    populateMapDetails(map);
        //                }, delay);
        //            }
        //            else { return (false); };
        //            isInitialView = false;
        //            return (false);
        //        });
    };


    $('.ic_container').click(function () {
        $('#accordion').fadeIn(400);
        var mapName = jQuery("img", this).attr("alt")
        isInitialView = false;

        $.each(maps.d, function (key, map) {
            if (map.MapName === mapName) {

                populateMapDetails(map);
            }
        });
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
    });

    //populate side bar with map details
    function populateMapDetails(map) {
        console.log("populating mapDetails for " + map.MapName);

        //$('#accordion').delay(delay).fadeIn(400);
        $("#MapName").html(map.MapName);
        $("#Description").html(map.Description);
        $("#DirectLinklink").attr("href", map.MapUrl);
        var imgSrc = map.MapName;
        var src = imgSrc.replace(/\s/g, ""); //remove white space
        $("#detailImg").attr("src", "Images/MapThumbs/" + src + ".png");
        $("#LaunchLink").attr("href", map.MapUrl);
        $("#txtEmbed").val(map.EmbedLink);

        //alert(map.MapName);
        //$('#accordion').delay(delay).fadeOut(400);

        //setInterval(function () { console.log("inside populateMapDetails"); }, delay);

    };





   });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just skimmed the code, but you're using setInteval, which will loop until you do a clearInterval, which is nowhere.

Comment: Since you mentioned you are new to JavaScript,you can debug JavaScript using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) on Firefox.

Comment: Yes thanks. However I have been having a lot of trouble getting firebug to run. So I am using the javascript console and debugger in chrome. This is very helpful. But I still cannot figure out why the .delay() (from jquery), setInterval() and setTimeout() seem to have no effect.

Comment: It is best when asking a question to try to rewrite your problematic code until you get create the smallest sample that reproduces your problem. The least you could do it remove the commented out code, surely your problem lies not there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line:

```
 setInterval(function () {
                populateMapDetails(maps.d[map]);
                              }, delay);
```

What your telling it do is to execute the populateMadDetails function every few seconds. So it will do this for each of your map items. is that what you want it do?

In your question you said you want it to :

> ```
> load a json file, then for each item in the json array, display its
> ```
>
> contents for a few seconds, then move
>   onto the next item in the array.

So in that case you want do something like:

```
populateMapDetails(maps.d[map])
setTimeout(..., delay);
```

Comment: I have tried with both setTimeOut() and setInterval() - but both give the same odd results.  The result is the now the each item in the array is being iterated over - as a loop should do - but its as if the setTimeOut or setInteval is being ignored. The loop executes without any pauses or delays.

Answer (score 0):

```
   setInterval(function () {
      populateMapDetails(maps.d[map]);
         }, delay);
```

Did you mean [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)?

Comment: I have tried with both setTimeOut() and setInterval(), and I am still getting the same strange result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the `map` variable in the for loop. Unlike many other C-like languages, variables in JavaScript are scoped to functions, not blocks. This means that the `map` variable is shared between all of the closures created in the loop. When the loop ends the map variable is pointing to the last index, and all of the callbacks will use that last index.

You can create a function and execute it straight away to close over the map variable like this:

```
setInterval((function(map) {
    return function() {
        populateMapDetails(maps.d[map]);
    };
})(map), delay);
```